# Dante 1.4.1 on CentOS config error

Tags: proxy, centos, socks

I am trying to configure Dante v1.4.1 on a CentOS release 6.7 (Final) machine with a lot of virtual NICs. I want external-rotation same-same.
I have tried this config:

```
internal: ip1 port = 1
internal: ip2 port = 1
.
.
.
external: ip1
external: ip2
.
.
.
external.rotation: same-same
method: none
user.privileged: <user>
user.unprivileged: <user>
client pass {
        from: <external_ip> port <port-range> to: 0.0.0.0/0
}
pass {
        from: <external_ip> <port-range> to: 0.0.0.0/0
         protocol: tcp udp
}
```

but i keep receiving this error message:

```
warning: getoutaddr(): using external.rotation = same-same, local address <external_ip> was selected for forwarding from our local client <external_ip> to target ip, but that local address is not set on our external interface(s).  Configuration error in /etc/sockd.conf?
```

If i don't use `external.rotation: same-same` everything works ok, but i want to make all the incoming traffic that enters on a vNIC to exit on the same vNIC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you managed to get your server running? I'm curious on the solution as well.

Comment: Yes, but my solution probably won't apply to you: I installed an Ubuntu LTS and got Dante 1.3.2 which I had installed on other server and worked like a charm. However, my advantage was that this was a fresh server :)